# What is the proper way to delete all elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am having trouble in deleting all elements from an array in mongodb. This is my schema:

```js
const userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    blog: [{
        date: Date,
        post: String
    }],
    week: [{
        weekday: String,
        tasks:[String]
    }],
    todo: [String]
});

const User= mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

I want to delete all data from todo but it is not working. Here is the code for that:

```js
app.post("/deletelist",(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const user = req.body.userid;
    console.log(user);

    // User.find({_id: user}, async function(err, foundUser){
    //     if(err){
    //         console.log(err);
    //     } else{
    //         foundUser.updateOne({},{ $set : {"todo": [] }} , {multi:true});
    //         // await foundUser.save();
    //         res.send("ToDo Deleted");
    //     }
    // });

    User.updateOne({_id:user},{ $set : {"todo": []}}, {multi:true});
    res.send("ToDo Deleted");

});
```

I am getting user from the frontend. The part that is commented and the other one(User.updateOne) both are not working. I'll be glad if anyone can help

Comment: `array.length = 0;`

Comment: I think the issue is that `{ $set: {"todo": [] } }` will not do anything because it's already an array and you don't provide specific values. I think I had this issue on one of my side projects. I ended up doing something like `{ $unset: {"todo": true } }` and right after this I called `{ $set: {"todo": [] } }`, but be careful because this operation is not atomic

Comment: @TimNimets is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Akshat I have found this code on the internet which looks prettier. `db.users.update({username: "tom"}, {$pull: {documents: {$exists: true}}})` you should try both. Also this issue is not directly from mongodb, but most likely from mongodb node driver, since manual updates in the console seem to works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated

You cannot use multi-option in the updateOne method remove it and it will work

**Example**

```js
User.updateOne({_id:user},{ $set : {"todo": []}})
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, it's saying that it's deprecated use UpdateOne or UpdateMany instead.

Comment: I just tried the code in the MongoDB shell and it's working fine for me

db.users.updateOne({id: 1}, {$set: {"todo": []}})

Comment: Look to the update!

Comment: It started working after I added a callback function to it.

Comment: User.updateOne({_id:user},{ $set : {"todo": []}}, function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(clg);
        } else{
            console.log(docs);
            res.send("ToDo Deleted");
        }
    });

Comment: I am not sure why a callback was mandatory to make it work. Please tell me if you know the reason for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this will remove all the elements even the key if you want to remove the elements only try **@Abdelrhman** answer

```
User.updateOne({_id:user},{$unset:{todo:""}})
```